# gatling rampConcurrentUsers not behaving as expected

Tags: gatling

I am using the following in my gatling simulation to inject users:

```
  setUp(
    includeScopesScenario.inject(rampConcurrentUsers(1).to(2).during(10))
  ).protocols(acsHttpProtocol)
```

However when I run the simulation it is starting with 10 users and dropping to 5 for the duration of the simulation. Here's the graph of active users:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here or am I misunderstanding how rampConcurrentUsers works?

Answer (score 0):

The stats you're seeing is not the number of concurrent users. The title of the chart explicitly states "Number of Active Users", see the [official documentation for its definition](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/stats/timings/#active-users).

The "concurrent users" stats is only available in Gatling Enterprise.
That being said, `rampConcurrentUsers` works completely fine.